# Prove that Matrix Multiplication is Associative.

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, summation, associativity

Q: In this exercise we show that matrix multiplication is associative. Suppose that $A$ is an $m*p$ matrix, $B$ is a $p*k$ matrix, and $C$ is a $k*n$ matrix. Show that $A(BC)=(AB)C$.

My solution:
.
$AB:m*k$ (There are p elements) and $[AB]_{i,j}=\sum_{m=1}^pa_{im}b_{mj}$.

$(AB)C:m*n$ (There are k elements)

$[(AB)C]_{i,j}=ab_{i1}c_{1j}+ab_{i2}c_{2j}+...+ab_{ik}c_{kj}$

$[(AB)C]_{i,j}=\sum_{n=1}^{k}ab_{in}c_{nj}$

$ab_{i1}=[AB]_{i,1}=\sum_{m=1}^pa_{im}b_{m1}$

$ab_{i2}=[AB]_{i,2}=\sum_{m=1}^pa_{im}b_{m2}$

...

$ab_{ik}=[AB]_{i,k}=\sum_{m=1}^pa_{im}b_{mk}$

Hence, $[(AB)C]_{i,j}=(\sum_{m=1}^pa_{im}b_{m1})c_{1j}+(\sum_{m=1}^pa_{im}b_{m2})c_{2j}+...+(\sum_{m=1}^pa_{im}b_{mk})c_{kj}$

We can abbreviate this long formula as:

$[(AB)C]_{i,j}=\sum_{n=1}^k(\sum_{m=1}^pa_{im}b_{mn})c_{nj} $

$[(AB)C]_{i,j}=\sum_{n=1}^k\sum_{m=1}^pa_{im}b_{mn}c_{nj} $

Now, let's look at $A(BC).$

$A(BC):m*n$ (ther are p elements)

$[A(BC)]_{i,j}=a_{i1}bc_{1j}+a_{i2}bc_{2j}+...+a_{ip}bc_{pj}$

$[A(BC)]_{i,j}=\sum_{m=1}^pa_{im}bc_{mj}$

$[BC]_{i,j}=\sum_{n=1}^kb_{in}c_{nj}$

We get

$[A(BC)]_{i,j}=\sum_{m=1}^{p}a_{im}\sum_{n=1}^{k}b_{mn}c_{nj} $

$[A(BC)]_{i,j}=\sum_{m=1}^{p}\sum_{n=1}^{k}a_{im}b_{mn}c_{nj} $

Since the sum is finite, we can change the order of summation.

Hence, $A(BC)=(AB)C$

Is my explanation correct? I am not sure about the logic behind the change of the position of summations. I will be thankful if someone can explain it.

Comment: Who is the person advising to close this question : it attests a lot of good work !

Comment: Usually, associativity of matrix product is obtained by bijective correspondence with linear functions.

Comment: Your proof is correct. Changing the order of summation amounts to this; if you take a grid of numbers, then total up the rows, and find the total of the row totals, the result is the same as totaling up the column totals. Therefore, changing the order of finite summations is obvious. You would only need to justify that in the most low-level proof contexts.